# C# Event: How does VisibleChange trigger?

Tags: c#, events, controls, panel

I'm building a program containing various `DataGridViews` on different `Panels`. The Panels are *stacked* on top of one another and when a particular Button is pressed, it brings its `Panel` to the through the `BringToFront` method. I found out experimentally that `VisibleChanged` fires when a `Panel` is brought to the front, even if its `Visible` property is not changed. So how does the `VisibleChanged` event actually trigger?

MSDN:
*This event is raised if the Visible property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.*

Comment: The Visible property is a bit wonky, its getter does not return the same value that was set by its setter.  You'll get *false* if the panel is not actually visible, usually because its Parent is not visible.  Stacking panels in the designer is very troublesome, one panel will end up *inside* of another panel.  Use View > Other Windows > Document Outline to verify that this did not happen.

Comment: Oh. Now I understand. Thanks! Yeah, I'm already using document outline :)